How can i deploy react app to Azure using az cli?
I have an app frontend  react app backend c#. I want to deploy the app to Azure. I am trying to deploy using az cli cmdlets.
I am using
az webapp up --name <app_name> --resource-group <resource_group_name> --sku S1

The app_name is my app service name in azure. I have tried deploying from Visual Studio but when i run my app it is a blank screen.
The app service in Azure is configured under Stack as .NET
The issue is where do i define the .csproj to deploy ?
How can i deploy the App to Azure ?

Can you please share your Code Repo ?

I simply have a visual studio project that I compile on my local drive. That's it. Do I need to creaye a zip and use az web deploy ?

I have a gulpfile.js and to build the project I type gulp prod  that's for production and gulp dev for development. So do I need to add something to the gulfile.js for a deploy command ?

What does gulpfile.js contained? can you share more detailes and code?

@Kristen - Is it ok if the app works when deployed from Visual Studio OR you are looking only for powershell?

No it doesn't work whe deployed from visual studio. When it starts up it's a blank screen. Browser error is " cant find a .js file" . When I deploy i right click on the project and publish,  is that correct or should I build and deploy from a folder that gets created , how does it work ?

Will check from my end once and let you know.

Does the root folder wwwroot has all the files deployed to it?

It looks lie it doies but i think the backend dlls are not there or deployed ?


How can i deploy react app to Azure using az cli?

To deploy any application to web app using zip file you can use below command and I have followed Microsoft-Document:
az webapp deploy --resource-group rgname --name rithwebapp --src-path "ReactApp1.zip" --async true

--src-path  here give the path of zip file
Output:


and to create the zip file ? is that just using powershells Compress-Archive ?

No I just used Compress to zip file https://i.imgur.com/kP1ZJs9.png

which directory of the solution do i need to be to create the zip file ? Is it the clientapp ?

can i create the zip from within Visual Studio ?
